# Laravel Eloquent collection my scopes

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to collect 6 scopes in one for more easy using them. Is it possible with laravel? Here is where I use them:

```
public function listSchoolsEndUser()
{
    $schools_data = new School;

    if ( Input::has('specialties') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereSpecialties(Input::get('specialties'));
    }

    if ( Input::has('district') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereDistrict(Input::get('district'));
    }

    if ( Input::has('municipality') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereMunicipality(Input::get('municipality'));
    }

    if ( Input::has('city') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereCity(Input::get('city'));
    }

    if ( Input::has('type') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereType(Input::get('type'));
    }

    if ( Input::has('financing') ) {
        $schools_data = $schools_data->whereFinancing(Input::get('financing'));
    }

    $schools_data = $schools_data->paginate(12);

    return $schools_data;
}
```

I need to use these filters many times and I don't see reason to repeat same code again.

Edit: my example scope scope

```
public function scopeWhereDistrict($query, $districts)
{
    if(! is_array($districts))
    {
        $districts = [$districts];
    }

    return $query->where(function($q) use ($districts)
    {
        foreach ($districts as $district)
        {
            $q->whereHas('city.municipality', function ($q) use ($district) {
                $q->where('district_id', '=', $district);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping through all the inputs and adding the where's should work:

```
$schools_data = School::query();
$filters = Input::only('specialities', 'district', 'municipality', 'city', 'type', 'financing');

foreach($filters as $filter => $value){
   call_user_func(array($schools_data, 'where' . studly_case($filter)), $value);
}

return $schools_data->paginate(12);
```

Comment: Is this work because I have scopes like in example in updated question?

Comment: When I use this code it's call scope without there is value of filter. Do I have to use if to check?

Comment: Non-existing inputs are covered by the input only method. If you possible have empty strings you can add an if clause.

Comment: When in url doesn't exist these queries, all of them are using in foreach and throw error. I think to add if clause in scopes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly

Comment: When filter values are empty is this correct to add if clause to scopes?

Comment: That's really up to you. You could also call do `$filters = array_filter($filters)` before the foreach loop. This will filter all values out that evaluates to false. Things like `""`, `0` and `null`

Comment: Okay. By the way, I rejected your edit because assigning the result of `call_user_func` is not necessary since your always dealing with the same query builder instance. (Note it's important when retrieving the result though)

Comment: But if I don't add call_user_func to his variable, added filters doesn't work.

Comment: Really? That surprises me

Comment: I found my mistake. I need to make a Query instance not a Model :)